# I need to use the feature additional columns in Source when insert into sql Server but no additional columns is created

Tags: azure

I have a ForEachFile activity that get the files from GetMetaData.The files is json.
Within this ForEachFile activity I have a copy that should insert the contents into a sql server database table and in addition add the current filename as an extra column to the database table.
So I have google and find several example where they use the feature additional columns. So I thought that this should be easy.
So in the additional columns in the Source I add a dynamic column with Filename and value as @item.name because each iteration in the ForEachFile loop will have @item.name as the filename.Here is a screen shot for ther Source [image]

All the values in the json file is inserted into the database but the filename is empty.
If I create the table first and then run the pipeline and can see that the Filename column is null. If I let sink create the table I can see that no Filename column is created.

Mapping
[image]

When I have added this to the mapping [image]

I get this error [image]

Here is the input to activity copyJsonToSql. Note I have three of these because I have three files so the value of "additionalColumns" is different
{
"source": {
"type": "JsonSource",
"additionalColumns": "516e59b7-13cd-46e9-a0c7-1d04e16b4b00.json",
"storeSettings": {
"type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
"recursive": true,
"enablePartitionDiscovery": false
},
"formatSettings": {
"type": "JsonReadSettings"
}
},
"sink": {
"type": "SqlServerSink",
"writeBehavior": "insert",
"sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
"tableOption": "autoCreate"
},
"enableStaging": false,
"translator": {
"type": "TabularTranslator",
"mappings": [
{
"source": {
"path": "['id']"
},
"sink": {
"name": "id",
"type": "String"
}
},
{
"source": {
"path": "['direction']"
},
"sink": {
"name": "direction",
"type": "String"
}
},
{
"source": {
"path": "['count']"
},
"sink": {
"name": "count",
"type": "String"
}
},
{
"source": {
"path": "['date']"
},
"sink": {
"name": "date",
"type": "String"
}
},
{
"source": {
"path": "['Filename']"
},
"sink": {
"name": "Filename",
"type": "String"
}
}
],
"collectionReference": "$['counts']['count']",
"mapComplexValuesToString": true
}
}

Here I have added the relevant activity in the pipeline
[image]

Now I get null as the filename in spite having added Filename as an addition columns as @item().name. I also used Add dynamic content and here I choose processeachJsonFile current item.
New screen shot [image]

Many thanks in advance
Tony Johansson

Comment: Can you share the mapping of copy activity?(screenshot)

Comment: Now you have the mapping. First I thought I could solve it with a stored procedure and pass the name but I have noticed that the copy activity do all the copy of all the files before going to the next activity

Comment: Now I get error  when added Filename to the mapping see my update. The error is 'The value of property additionalColumns' is an unexpected type 'IList' 1'

Comment: Could you share input of any one of the copy activity when you run the pipeline? Click input  [img](https://i.imgur.com/LQFgD4A.png) and share the response

Comment: A new update with shows input to CopyjsonToSql

Comment: In addition I have added the relevant activities in the pipeline so you get full understanding

Comment: When adding additional columns in source, Click the `+new ` in additional column and give the column name and add @item().name as a dynamic value. Refer the [img](https://i.imgur.com/H29DRff.png)

Comment: Don't add the column name directly by ckicking add a dynamic content in additonal column. [img](https://i.imgur.com/cbYDr4U.png)

Comment: Now I get null as Filename. I have also had this before. You can see my update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253191/discussion-between-tony-and-aswin).

Comment: I thought it would be easy to just add the filename to Sql Server when insert into sql server in a foreachfile activity

Comment: I tried this that I thought shouold work.

Comment: I Used a stored procedure in the same ForEachFile just after the copy. In the stored procedure pass in the filename @item.name and update the table with the passed filename as an arument where the filename is null. But the result was that all rown in the database tabel had the same filename

Answer (score 0):

- In order to copy the value of additional column to the sink table, you need to alter the mapping settings that is defined already.
- In mapping tab of copy activity, click on **Import schema**.
- All fields from source along with additional column got imported.
- Map the additional column to the respective field in sink.
  [image]
- Execute the pipeline, data will be copied to sink.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it as I indented in the first place.
In the foreach activity I have a copy called CopyJsonToSql and after that a stored procedure. In the CopyJsonToSql I insert the data from the Json files into the db table and the column called filename will be null because there is no data in the jsonfile called Filename. In the stored procedure SaveFilenameToSql I pass the filename as @item().name. The stored procedure update ther database table with correct filename. The stored procedure look

```
like this 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[p_CarCounter]
@Filename varchar(100)
as
begin
    update dbo.CarCounter
    set Filename = @Filename
    where Filename is null;
end
```